# Select2 4.0 caching data from ajax call to a variable

Tags: jquery-select2

Is there a way to cache ajax results to a variable in select2 4.0 so the next time the box is clicked it pulls from the local cache vs doing ajax call again?

Answer (score -2):

Store your result in a global variable and check the variable has contents before doing ajax call.

**OR**

Try using the ajax.processResults option to process the data returned from the server before passing it to Select2.

```
enter code here$('select').select2({
                    ajax: {
                         url: '/example/api',
                         processResults: function (data) {
                                     //add data to global variable
                                     return {
                                          results: data.items
                                            };
                                 }
                          }
                      });
```

Comment: Yäsår in Select2 4.0 ajax is not a function. So how do I check?

Comment: I'm trying to prevent using ajax if the data is cached in the global variable. So if the global variable is not set then do ajax otherwise use global variable